# Javascript - print all names in array containing multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

So I'm new to javascript and programming in general and I have an array of objects below. I'm trying to generate and print an array containing the full names of students (first and last name separated by “ “) of all students who received an exam grade of 80 or higher. Sort of in the format like [ 'James Johnson', 'Stephanie Ottesen', 'Leonard Arvan', 'Beverly Mott', 'Beatrice Jaco' ].

I made a separate array already but I'm having trouble figuring out how to access only certain objects in an array and add them to my new array. From googling, I've come across the .map(), .reduce(), and .filter() methods but I'm struggling to figure out how to take these methods and format them into my program. Any help or references would be appreciated.

```
let students = [{fname: "Jane", lname: "Brazier", snum: "100366942", agrade: 67.59127376966494, tgrade: 64.86530868914188, egrade: 70.52944558104066}, {fname: "Ricardo", lname: "Allen", snum: "100345641", agrade: 65.80370345301014, tgrade: 75.40211705841241, egrade: 55.39348896202821}, {fname: "Mary", lname: "Hernandez", snum: "100221207", agrade: 71.20761408935981, tgrade: 71.37529197926764, egrade: 75.82038980457698}, {fname: "James", lname: "Johnson", snum: "100200842", agrade: 72.5791318299902, tgrade: 81.65883679807183, egrade: 85.19664228946989}, {fname: "Stephanie", lname: "Ottesen", snum: "100225067", agrade: 88.19738810849226, tgrade: 84.68339894849353, egrade: 82.23947265645927}, {fname: "Martin", lname: "Conway", snum: "100358379", agrade: 71.28759059295344, tgrade: 79.13194908266965, egrade: 77.61880623797336}, {fname: "Andrew", lname: "Weaver", snum: "100376243", agrade: 70.01798139244363, tgrade: 78.64811561086252, egrade: 78.68650242850617}, {fname: "Rhonda", lname: "Ford", snum: "100296902", agrade: 56.14580882764524, tgrade: 63.9209865108888, egrade: 60.186613967770334}, {fname: "Leonard", lname: "Arvan", snum: "100220616", agrade: 80.67865525396981, tgrade: 92.73557717342663, egrade: 88.32126970338336}, {fname: "William", lname: "Culler", snum: "100307637", agrade: 65.75251699043244, tgrade: 62.18172136246404, egrade: 63.065185542933094}, {fname: "David", lname: "Nakasone", snum: "100353719", agrade: 62.63260239883763, tgrade: 58.352794766947866, egrade: 59.80461902691901}, {fname: "Maria", lname: "Young", snum: "100311331", agrade: 70.13767021264486, tgrade: 76.09348747016176, egrade: 79.99207130929622}, {fname: "Beverly", lname: "Mott", snum: "100325579", agrade: 83.08140516644137, tgrade: 94.80666640692787, egrade: 85.15875656837004}, {fname: "Patrick", lname: "Francis", snum: "100257773", agrade: 66.79534616079296, tgrade: 47.744928296560076, egrade: 64.05723052865763}, {fname: "Tracy", lname: "Bonds", snum: "100233277", agrade: 70.2289028670531, tgrade: 65.32258294210156, egrade: 77.04816321925091}, {fname: "Richard", lname: "Akers", snum: "100216705", agrade: 52.446722363991015, tgrade: 49.205597783687374, egrade: 53.72940974941982}, {fname: "Beatrice", lname: "Jaco", snum: "100233935", agrade: 81.89338938644417, tgrade: 71.05459078971688, egrade: 83.08235397281308}, {fname: "Guy", lname: "Wendelin", snum: "100336379", agrade: 68.17788319655493, tgrade: 63.82273085525137, egrade: 68.31559946786807}, {fname: "Logan", lname: "Olsen", snum: "100265736", agrade: 59.89037739094347, tgrade: 71.76550299333657, egrade: 64.61665695830132}, {fname: "Gene", lname: "Jeanlouis", snum: "100341666", agrade: 74.16481515505846, tgrade: 68.20592386917109, egrade: 78.25975050135006}]

let studentNames = [];
```

Comment: why not pick one, like [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and have a look to the description and examples. try it and add the problem, if you have one to the question.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us an example, at least, otherwise we're just going to assume you're asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: It's fine if you're stuck in implementing but please post your effort to the question. You don't even need filter, map or reduce. A simple `for` loop through the array -> check `if (array[i].grade > 80)` -> `push` the full name to the output array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Extract only the students with grade 80 or higher with `Array.filter`.
2. Map the remaining students into a new format using `Array.map`.

Result:

```js
let students = [{
  fname: "Jane",
  lname: "Brazier",
  snum: "100366942",
  agrade: 67.59127376966494,
  tgrade: 64.86530868914188,
  egrade: 70.52944558104066
}, {
  fname: "Ricardo",
  lname: "Allen",
  snum: "100345641",
  agrade: 65.80370345301014,
  tgrade: 75.40211705841241,
  egrade: 55.39348896202821
}, {
  fname: "Mary",
  lname: "Hernandez",
  snum: "100221207",
  agrade: 71.20761408935981,
  tgrade: 71.37529197926764,
  egrade: 75.82038980457698
}, {
  fname: "James",
  lname: "Johnson",
  snum: "100200842",
  agrade: 72.5791318299902,
  tgrade: 81.65883679807183,
  egrade: 85.19664228946989
}, {
  fname: "Stephanie",
  lname: "Ottesen",
  snum: "100225067",
  agrade: 88.19738810849226,
  tgrade: 84.68339894849353,
  egrade: 82.23947265645927
}, {
  fname: "Martin",
  lname: "Conway",
  snum: "100358379",
  agrade: 71.28759059295344,
  tgrade: 79.13194908266965,
  egrade: 77.61880623797336
}, {
  fname: "Andrew",
  lname: "Weaver",
  snum: "100376243",
  agrade: 70.01798139244363,
  tgrade: 78.64811561086252,
  egrade: 78.68650242850617
}, {
  fname: "Rhonda",
  lname: "Ford",
  snum: "100296902",
  agrade: 56.14580882764524,
  tgrade: 63.9209865108888,
  egrade: 60.186613967770334
}, {
  fname: "Leonard",
  lname: "Arvan",
  snum: "100220616",
  agrade: 80.67865525396981,
  tgrade: 92.73557717342663,
  egrade: 88.32126970338336
}, {
  fname: "William",
  lname: "Culler",
  snum: "100307637",
  agrade: 65.75251699043244,
  tgrade: 62.18172136246404,
  egrade: 63.065185542933094
}, {
  fname: "David",
  lname: "Nakasone",
  snum: "100353719",
  agrade: 62.63260239883763,
  tgrade: 58.352794766947866,
  egrade: 59.80461902691901
}, {
  fname: "Maria",
  lname: "Young",
  snum: "100311331",
  agrade: 70.13767021264486,
  tgrade: 76.09348747016176,
  egrade: 79.99207130929622
}, {
  fname: "Beverly",
  lname: "Mott",
  snum: "100325579",
  agrade: 83.08140516644137,
  tgrade: 94.80666640692787,
  egrade: 85.15875656837004
}, {
  fname: "Patrick",
  lname: "Francis",
  snum: "100257773",
  agrade: 66.79534616079296,
  tgrade: 47.744928296560076,
  egrade: 64.05723052865763
}, {
  fname: "Tracy",
  lname: "Bonds",
  snum: "100233277",
  agrade: 70.2289028670531,
  tgrade: 65.32258294210156,
  egrade: 77.04816321925091
}, {
  fname: "Richard",
  lname: "Akers",
  snum: "100216705",
  agrade: 52.446722363991015,
  tgrade: 49.205597783687374,
  egrade: 53.72940974941982
}, {
  fname: "Beatrice",
  lname: "Jaco",
  snum: "100233935",
  agrade: 81.89338938644417,
  tgrade: 71.05459078971688,
  egrade: 83.08235397281308
}, {
  fname: "Guy",
  lname: "Wendelin",
  snum: "100336379",
  agrade: 68.17788319655493,
  tgrade: 63.82273085525137,
  egrade: 68.31559946786807
}, {
  fname: "Logan",
  lname: "Olsen",
  snum: "100265736",
  agrade: 59.89037739094347,
  tgrade: 71.76550299333657,
  egrade: 64.61665695830132
}, {
  fname: "Gene",
  lname: "Jeanlouis",
  snum: "100341666",
  agrade: 74.16481515505846,
  tgrade: 68.20592386917109,
  egrade: 78.25975050135006
}];

const result = students
  .filter(student => student.egrade >= 80)
  .map(student => `${student.fname} ${student.lname}`);
  
console.log(result);
```